# Why dose Python List append the same thing?

Tags: python, list, append

I have a question when I use list.append().
In the following Code, the append() append the same thing n times, why would that happen?

```
ret=['aaa']
def generateMessage(num):
    ret[0]=num
    return (ret)

outputfile=[]
for cnt in range(0,5):
    # print(cnt)
    tmp=generateMessage(cnt)
    print("TMP is: ")
    print(tmp)
    outputfile.append(tmp)
    print("OutputFile is: ")
    print(outputfile)
print(outputfile)
```

This problem will not happen on this:

```
ret=[]
def generateMessage(num):
    ret=num
    return (ret)

outputfile=[]
for cnt in range(0,5):
    # print(cnt)
    tmp=generateMessage(cnt)
    print("TMP is: ")
    print(tmp)
    outputfile.append(tmp)
    print("OutputFile is: ")
    print(outputfile)
print(outputfile)
```

Can any one explain this to me?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Because when the program ends `outputfile` is `[ret, ret, ret, ret, ret]` which is `[[5], [5], [5], [5], [5]]` .

Answer (score 0):

The following takes `ret` assigns its first item to `num` and returns `ret`:

```
ret=['aaa']
def generateMessage(num):
    ret[0]=num
    return (ret)
```

All the returned lists are the same list. You need to return a new list each time

```
def generateMessage(num):
    return [num]
```

Comment: But the returned list have a new value each time. By print I find that its value is: 0,1,2,3,4

Comment: Yes but check that `tmp is ret` is True. Which means that every item appended is the same list.

Comment: Thanks, is it because when I write `ret=['aaa']` , `ret` is a `List object`, and `output` changes with `ret`